# Second Isomorphism Theorem for Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I am looking for verification of the following:

Let $X$ be a Banach space. We will show that if $M, N$ and $M+N$ are closed subspaces of $X$, then
$$\dfrac{M+N}{N} \cong \dfrac{M}{M \cap N},$$
using the map $\phi : M \to \dfrac{M+N}{N}$, where $x \mapsto x + N$. For any $x,y \in M$, we have that,
$$\phi(x+y) = (x+y) + N = (x + N) + (y + N) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$$
Also, for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$, we have,
$$\phi(\lambda x) = (\lambda x) + N = \lambda(x + N) = \lambda\phi(x)$$
Then:
\begin{align*}
\ker(\phi) &= \left\{ m \in M : \phi(m) = e_{\frac{M+N}{N}} \right\} \hspace{1cm}\text{should this be sent to 0 instead of the "identity"?}\\
&= \left\{ m \in M : m + N = N \right\} \\
&= \left\{ m \in M : m \in N \right\} \\
&= M \cap N
\end{align*}
Then, we see that $\phi$ is a surjection because 
$$(m+n) + N = m + N \in \dfrac{M+N}{N}$$
which is $\phi(m)$. Then, we use the first isomorphism theorem, that is, for any operator $\phi: X \to Y$ between Banach spaces,
$$X / \ker(\phi) \cong \text{im} \phi \iff \text{im}\phi \space\ \text{is closed in} \space\ Y$$
So that here, $X = M$, $\ker(\phi) = M \cap N$, and $Y = \text{im}(\phi) = \dfrac{M+N}{N}$, so that the result follows.

Comment: Please make explicit what it is that you're actually asking here.

Comment: Proof verification, was unsure if I proved it correctly.

Comment: More so cautious to whether or not I missed something in the proof, did I show everything that needs to be shown here? Or does this proof basically mirror the one from intro abstract algebra courses?

Comment: To answer your question in the middle: indeed, $e_{(M+N)/N} = 0$.  $0$ is the identity with respect to the group operation of addition.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your proof should mirror that of the second isomorphism theorem.  In fact, this statement is (almost) an instance of the [second isomorphism theorem for modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem_3), except for the fact that our $\phi$ (and eventually our isomoprhism) must also be continuous.

Your proof is correct except for two things:

- You should write $0$ instead of $e$ (although your version is also technically correct)
- You should note that $\phi$ is continuous, as is the induced map on $X/ \ker \phi$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.